# Problema Sesion. "No se pudo descifrar el token antifalsificación" ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy teniendo un error en la aplicación y no encuentro mucha información en Internet sobre eso, quisiera que me ayudaran por favor.

**Seguimiento de la pila:**

```
Seguimiento de la pila:
```

> [HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): No se pudo descifrar el token antifalsificación. En caso de que esta aplicación esté alojada en una Web Farm o clúster, asegúrese de que todos los equipos ejecuten la misma versión de ASP.NET Web Pages y de que la configuración de  especifique claves de validación y cifrado explícitas. AutoGenerate no puede utilizarse en un clúster.]
>      System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken) +337
>      System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryTokenStore.GetFormToken(HttpContextBase httpContext) +91
>      System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext) +44
>      System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate() +92
>      System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +18
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +97
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

La aplicación la estaba desarrollando en `Visual Studio 2015` y lo pase a 2017, supongo que tendrá algo que ver, aunque en un principio me estuvo funcionando entonces descarte que la migración allá tenido algún error.

La aplicación se hizo sobre una **plantilla de MVC 5** con autenticación individual de usuarios.

La app compila y se ejecuta normalmente, el problema ocurre cuando tengo un usuario logueado y luego le doy al botón cerrar sesión.

Comment: Coloca el código fuente por favor :D y mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. Saludos y bienvenido :D

Comment: Sin el código de como recibes el token y como haces post desde la vista no podremos ayudarte mucho, de momento [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766975/requestverificationtoken-does-not-match) te puede ayudar un poco.